# Martingale problem for aging particle system

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

I have this problem at the moment and I'm not sure what to do at all:

Let $d>0,$ N be a $\lambda-$Poisson process and ${\{z^i\}}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of aging particles such that:

i)Their initial ages ${\{z_0^i\}}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are the success of $N_{[0,d)}$ or $\infty$ once the successes run out.

ii)Each particle ages as $$z_t^i=\frac{z_0^i e^{-bt}}{1-\beta z_0^i \int_0^t e^{-bs}ds}$$
until its death at age $d.$

iii)Each living particle at age $z<d$ gives birth to a new particle at rate $2a(d-z)$ with the age of the new particle being the [a,d]-uniform.

Let $$D_0={\{g\in C(\mathbb{R}):0\le g\le1,g(z)=1 \text{ when } z\ge d\}}$$
So that every g is eventually 1. Let D be the infinite product functions
$$f(z)=\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}g(z^i)$$
Find the martingale for the infinite vector of ages $z^i.$
That is to find an operator $L$ such that
$$f(Z_t)-f(Z_0)-\int_0^t Lf(Z_s)ds$$
is a martingale where
$$Z_s=\begin{bmatrix}
z_s^1\\
z_s^2\\
\vdots
\end{bmatrix}$$

I understand each individual part of the question but have no clue where to even start putting them together within the martingale. Would appreciate some help on this, thanks.